# React useEffect clean up function runs multiple times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

React hook noob here...

Given this example

```
useEffect(() => {
    function handleStatusChange(status) {
      setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
    }

    ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    // Specify how to clean up after this effect:
    return function cleanup() {
      ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    };
  });
```

From the doc

> React performs the cleanup when the component unmounts. However, as we learned earlier, effects run for every render and not just once. This is why React also cleans up effects from the previous render before running the effects next time.

Does that mean `unsubscribeFromFriendStatus` only gets run when once when component unmounts or every render?

**Extending my question:**

if `unsubscribeFromFriendStatus` gets run every time, and the only way to skip it is by using optional second argument... then doesn't it make it harder to implement the original explicit execution of `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUnmount`? Say, I want to `subscribe` when `componentWillMount`, and only run `unsubscribe` when `componentWillUnMount`?

Comment: As per the docs *This is why React also cleans up effects from the previous render before running the effects next time*. So **YES**, it'll run on every render.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does that mean `unsubscribeFromFriendStatus` only gets run when once when component unmounts or every render?

`unsubscribeFromFriendStatus` runs **every re-render**.

Every re-render, *even if `props.friend.id` never changed*, it unsubscribes and resubscribes.

To improve this, run the effect **only when `props.friend.id` changed**.
This is possible by adding it as a dependency to `useEffect()`.

```
useEffect(
  () => { /* subscription */ }
  , [props.friend.id] // add as dependency
)
```

> doesn't it make it harder to implement the original explicit execution of componentWillMount and componentWillUnmount? Say, I want to subscribe when componentWillMount, and only run unsubscribe when componentWillUnMount?

It doesn't make sense to maintain old subscriptions using old values of `props.friend.id`.

A subscription uses a resource (websocket or observer). When unsubscribing during `componentWillUnmount` is only unsubscribing the latest value of your `props.friend.id`.

What happens to the older subscriptions? Not freed.
Thus, you have a **memory leak**.

Comment: perhaps `subscribe` and `unsubscribe` is a bad example, which is against `open late` and `close early`, but let's say I only want to do certain things at `componentWillMount` and certain things only when `componentWillUnmount`?

Comment: If you only want to run the effect once, just add `[]` as the second argument.

Comment: But that `once` doesn't specify "when" to run? I want it to specifically run at "start" and another run at "end"

Comment: @JamesLin passing an empty array `[]` would only run the effect on mount and unmount. You can read more about that in this section: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

Comment: Makes sense now. I was confusing myself.