# Why useEffect cleanup logging every time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm implementing count down
and use `useRef` hook to using it when clean setTimeout when the user navigates to the next screen to avoid `cancel all subscription warning` and it's work!

But I have something weird when count - 1 i can see "hey" in the console! although not cleaning the setTimeOut!!

I don't want to clean it in this case but why should loggin every time count changes!

code snippet

```
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(40);
  const countRef = useRef(seconds);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (seconds > 0) {
      countRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
        setSeconds(seconds - 1);
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      setSeconds(0);
    }
    return () => {
      console.log('hey'); // every count down it's appeared 
      clearTimeout(countRef.current);
    };
  }, [seconds]);
```

Comment: Because of the dependency on `seconds`, which you change every iteration.

Comment: @AKX well, But why clearTimeout() not invoke?

Comment: Why you say that clearTimeout isn't being invoked? It is being invoked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React useEffect clean up function runs multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58424470/react-useeffect-clean-up-function-runs-multiple-times)

Comment: @Vencovsky but i can see the count down work `10 9 8`!

Answer (score 2):

You see "hey" because you're using seconds as a dependency. So every time seconds changes, the effect must run again leading to the effect's destroy function (the function you returned from the effect) to be invoked.

Instead of having seconds as a dependency, you should instead have setSeconds.

```js
const [seconds, setSeconds] = React.useState(10);

useEffect(() => {
  let didUnsub = false;

  const id = setInterval(() => {
    setSeconds((prev) => {
      // while the count is greater than 0, continue to countdown
      if (prev > 0) {
        return prev - 1;
      }

      // once count eq 0, stop counting down
      clearInterval(id);
      didUnsub = true;

      return 0;
    });
  }, 1000);

  return () => {
    console.log("unmounting");
    // if the count didn't unsubscribe by reaching 0, clear the interval
    if (!didUnsub) {
      console.log("unsubscribing");
      clearInterval(id);
    }
  };
}, [setSeconds]);
```

If you look at the example below, you'll see that the effect is only run once, when the component is mounted. If you were to cause the component to dismount, the destroy function would be invoked. This is because the setState is a dispatch function and doesn't change between renders, therefor it doesn't cause the effect to continuously be called.

In the example you can click the button to toggle between mounting and dismounting the counter. When you dismount it notice that it logs in the console.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-silence-ui0pv?file=/src/Countdown.js